# Octohost with knife solo on bare metal? (UserError: Vagrant not installed)

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, docker, provisioning

I want do deploy [octohost](https://github.com/octohost/octohost-cookbook) on a bare metal server. As far as I understand so far knife solo is intended to use ssh to do the chef provisioning direct on a server?

But, when I follow the [second step](http://www.octohost.io/knife-solo.html), I get:

```
~/octohost-cookbook$ sudo rake knife_solo user=root ip=172.16.90.151 rake aborted! Kitchen::UserError: Vagrant 1.1.0 or higher is not installed. Please download a package from http://downloads.vagrantup.com/.
```

Is there really no way to do use knife solo to install octohost on a machine without the capacity to run VMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is happening because the `rake` command uses `bundle exec` to execute. The [bundle includes Test Kitchen and kitchen-vagrant](https://github.com/octohost/octohost-cookbook/blob/26d3a41c6de7c4c93dcbf4f89224662ded4ebd8f/Gemfile#L17-L18), which require the presence of Vagrant to run.

You can disable these by running:

```
bundle install --without integration
```

Or by removing them from your `Gemfile`.